# How to shift a single menu item in bootstrap 4 to the right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, html-lists

I am using Bootstrap 4 as part of a Laravel 8 blog system I am doing now. The menu items are well in place but I want to shift the last menu item to the right. I have tried many options including `ml-auto` but it  does not have any effect on the item. I also tried to benefit from previous similar posts but they all proved not to work for my case. I would so much appreciate any assistance in this regard. Please find my code below:

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">{{config('app.name', 'Learning')}}</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="nav navbar-nav">

          <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="/about">About Us</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="/services">Services</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="/posts">Blog</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="/posts/create">Create Post</a>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue is that you say you are using Bootstrap 4, but your syntax is of Bootstrap 5. `data-bs-*` attributes are for B5, B4 has only `data-*` attributes.

Then for aligning the last item to the right, first you'll need your `navbar-nav` to take all width, thus add `w-100` to it. Then you'll need the last item to fill all the remaining space, which you can do by adding `flex-fill`. And then all you need to do is add the `text-end` to this same element. Your code becomes:

```
<div class="nav navbar-nav w-100">
    <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home</a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="/about">About Us</a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="/services">Services</a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="/posts">Blog</a>
    <a class="nav-link flex-fill text-end" href="/posts/create">Create Post</a>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deathstalkersid/ac28p917/3/)

Again, if you are indeed not using B5, but B4, then change all the `data-bs-*` attributes to only `data-*`, and also `text-end` becomes `text-right`.

Comment: You were right, once I changed the Bootstrap library to B5, all your tags worked perfectly. Thank you so much, this has solved it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by adding this css line:

```
.nav-link:last-child {
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```